# GAUL library seems do not work

Tags: genetic-algorithm, gaul

I am learning how to use GAUL right now. I started from the first example struggle.c
I can understand it and run it successfully. However it seems like the best result can never be the same as the target string.

The target string is "When we reflect on this struggle, we may console ourselves with the full belief, that the war of nature is not incessant, that no fear is felt, that death is generally prompt, and that the vigorous, the healthy, and the happy survive and multiply."

The GA run 50 times and the best result is something like that

"When w^ yeil^ct%on%this strsggln,#we may console ourselves nith,she gbll ^eomef' that&thk wir#od(n`qure bl nfx kgciss\nt,)what no#bear is-[egt, wh_t deaxh is g_jerally promph, an` s[at+th] v`gormxs, rhe'he_jshy,&apd the hapsy survivT`na#kqitiphy."

Is this normal or I installed wrong somehow? Thanks.
Here is the link for the tutorial of struggle.c 
http://gaul.sourceforge.net/tutorial/simple.html

Comment: Give it more iterations

Comment: @trailmax There are 500 iterations, I tried 1000, still cannot do better. I just want to know if this example is just illustrative thus doesn't  really perform well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with GAUL but for this type of example elitism normally makes a big difference.  If you can turn that on you'll probably see much faster convergence as you're not constantly discarding good partial solutions.

As an alternative to increasing the number of generations, you could instead try increasing the population size so that you have more diversity to work with.  You could also try altering the mutation rate.  If you're using the 0.2 mentioned on the page that you're linking to it could be a bit high.  When mutation is too frequent it undermines the progress that the algorithm is making.

If you just want to see the program find the target string you could try using a shorter string.  The longer the string the more generations it will take to converge.

Comment: Thanks Dan, it's really detailed. I just thought the example should give the exact target which seems not to be the case. Also if working with binary gene which just reduces the searching space, it will converge much faster. Thanks